# Root on Kali SSH server

Tags: linux, ssh, android, kali-linux, root

Basically what I've done is installed linux deploy, deployed Kali on an SSH server.  Then I installed termux, ran :
ssh root@localhost 
It then asked me the password to login, I input the default "toor", but it got denied then i tryed the password that I had set up in the linux deploy configurations. Still didn't work.
Any clues?

Comment: Do not ssh with root. ssh with normal user and run commands with sudo.

Comment: yes but when i do so i log in without having su permissions, even if i try "su"

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve this, like setting up SSH keys (certificates), changing the SSH server configuration to allow root login (not recommended!), or giving your user 'su" permissions. Have you tried them? What was the result?

Comment: I've tried to setup "su" on termux but for multiple reasons it fails, havent tried SSH keys thought, i'll give it a go and I've changed ssh cinfigurations to allow root. What if SSH keys fail, what should i do then? Oh and also I've set up the ssh conection with Linux Deploy, can't configure much there.